# how to set NSArray values to UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am using xml parsing and have my values stored in array called fetchedobj. Now i want the values in array fetchedobj to be displayed to UILabel.

There are five UILabels and on click of a button i want the  five values to be displayed on five UILabels. on next click the values are to be incremented and UILabels should be updated with next set of five values

```
for ( i=0; i<fetchedobj.count; )
    {
        n1.text=[[fetchedobj objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"tag"];
        n2.text=[[fetchedobj objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"person"];
        n3.text=[[fetchedobj objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"place"];
        n4.text=[[fetchedobj objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"gENDER"];
         n5.text=[[fetchedobj objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"ph"];



        i++;
    }
```

using this code the details of last person is displayed on UILabels. plz help

Answer (score -1):

If i am getting your question right, you want to do this -- 
Firstly make a global NSInteger variable and assign it as 0 in viewDidLoad(). (i.e. currentIndex = 0). And  use this

```
 -(IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender 
 {
    currentIndex = currentIndex + 1;  
    if(currentIndex >[fetchedobj count]-1 )
          currentIndex = 0;  

    // here set your values  
   n1.text=[[fetchedobj objectAtIndex: currentIndex]valueForKey:@"tag"];
   -----
   -----
 }
```